# C Command line arguments in existing C Code

Tags: c

I am setting up a PHP page to control some basic sensors using a raspberry pi.  I working off my own PHP code but it has been years since I've even touched coding and I'm at a loss when it comes to C.  I've compiled the code below and it runs great and I get data back from the sensor.  I'll be able to get the data ported into PHP without an issue.  What I would like to be able to do is pass an argument to the compiled C program that would be which PIN to read off the raspberry pi.

`define DHT_PIN 29` (The number 29 is what I would like to be passed through command line arguments.)

C Code:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_TIMINGS 85
#define DHT_PIN 29
int data[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

void read_dht_data()
{
    uint8_t laststate    = HIGH;
    uint8_t counter        = 0;
    uint8_t j            = 0, i;

    data[0] = data[1] = data[2] = data[3] = data[4] = 0;

    /* pull pin down for 18 milliseconds */
    pinMode( DHT_PIN, OUTPUT );
    digitalWrite( DHT_PIN, LOW );
    delay( 18 );

    /* prepare to read the pin */
    pinMode( DHT_PIN, INPUT );

    /* detect change and read data */
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_TIMINGS; i++ )
    {
        counter = 0;
        while ( digitalRead( DHT_PIN ) == laststate )
        {
            counter++;
            delayMicroseconds( 1 );
            if ( counter == 255 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        laststate = digitalRead( DHT_PIN );

        if ( counter == 255 )
            break;

        /* ignore first 3 transitions */
        if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
        {
            /* shove each bit into the storage bytes */
            data[j / 8] <<= 1;
            if ( counter > 16 )
                data[j / 8] |= 1;
            j++;
        }
    }

    /*
     * check we read 40 bits (8bit x 5 ) + verify checksum in the last byte
     * print it out if data is good
     */

    if ( (j >= 40) &&
         (data[4] == ( (data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3]) & 0xFF) ) )
    {
        float h = (float)((data[0] << 8) + data[1]) / 10;
        if ( h > 100 )
        {
            h = data[0];    // for DHT11
        }
        float c = (float)(((data[2] & 0x7F) << 8) + data[3]) / 10;
        if ( c > 125 )
        {
            c = data[2];    // for DHT11
        }
        if ( data[2] & 0x80 )
        {
            c = -c;
        }
        printf( "%.1f %% %.1f *C\n", h, c );
    }
    else  {
       printf( "Data not good, skip\n" );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "DHT22 temperature/humidity test\n" );

    if ( wiringPiSetup() == -1 )
        exit( 1 );

    read_dht_data();
}
```

I've tried reading but C is not my language. I'm asking for some help to accomplish my task.

Comment: Can't really do this (`#define`) via command line arguments as macros are expanded at compile time. Could initialize a static variable instead. Or could pass "-DDHT_PIN=29` when compiling.

Comment: @MFisherKDX The OP clearly stated "pass an argument to the compiled C program", both options you present are incorrect. The application needs to be altered to parse the command line argument provided by the user at run time.

Comment: @EricPaquette please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Geoffrey ... "initialize a variable" would satisfy the OPs requirement. All he has to do is parse it from argv and use a variable instead if a macro. Not sure what you are arguing about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter your prototype for your `main` function and then parse the arguments provided:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_TIMINGS 85
int data[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

void read_dht_data(long dhtPin)
{
    uint8_t laststate    = HIGH;
    uint8_t counter        = 0;
    uint8_t j            = 0, i;

    data[0] = data[1] = data[2] = data[3] = data[4] = 0;

    /* pull pin down for 18 milliseconds */
    pinMode( dhtPin, OUTPUT );
    digitalWrite( dhtPin, LOW );
    delay( 18 );

    /* prepare to read the pin */
    pinMode( dhtPin, INPUT );

    /* detect change and read data */
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_TIMINGS; i++ )
    {
        counter = 0;
        while ( digitalRead( dhtPin ) == laststate )
        {
            counter++;
            delayMicroseconds( 1 );
            if ( counter == 255 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        laststate = digitalRead( dhtPin );

        if ( counter == 255 )
            break;

        /* ignore first 3 transitions */
        if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
        {
            /* shove each bit into the storage bytes */
            data[j / 8] <<= 1;
            if ( counter > 16 )
                data[j / 8] |= 1;
            j++;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("You must specify the DHT pin\n");
    return 1;
  }

  char *end;
  long dhtPin = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
  if (end == argv[1])
  {
    printf("Invalid number\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if ( wiringPiSetup() == -1 )
    return 1;

  read_dht_data(dhtPin);
  return 0;
}
```

If you need more complex argument parsing see the [`getopt`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  This worked like a charm.  Had to add the print out as it was ommited from your answer.  But it was an easy alteration.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Use argv[] like so (assuming the argument is an integer):

```
int dht_pin = atoi(argv[1])
```

You'll need to define main as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ ... }
```

atoi() is part of stdlib.h

Comment: Don't advocate the usage of `atoi`, it is impossible to detect failure to parse, espesially when zero is a valid input, instead `strtol` should be used.